# Mediasoup: Connection state changed to disconnected a few tens of seconds after connected

Tags: mediasoup

We use mediasoup to create our products. However, I am having problems with the transport connection.

The client transport connection state goes disconnected a few eights seconds after connection.
The following log will be output in the chrome console.

```
mediasoup-client:Transport connection state changed to connected
```

However, the following log will be output in the chrome console a few eights seconds later

```
mediasoup-client:Transport connection state changed to disconnected
```

If the NewProducer is present before the disconnection, the above will not happen.
Do you know the possible causes?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I changed the AWS security policy according to the topic below and it worked.

```
You’ll also need to configure your AWS Security Group to allow TCP/UDP on whatever port range you’re using.
```

https://mediasoup.discourse.group/t/docker-setup-with-listenips/2557/4